# PHP PDO output in angular

Tags: php, angularjs, pdo

I am trying to get output in Angular via PHP PDO but unable to understand the error.
When I write the same code using PHP procedural way (mysqli) then I can easily fetch the output. But I am struggling in fetching data with PHP PDO.

Here is my code:

Index.php:

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="fieldcontroller" ng-init="displayData()">  
   <tr ng-repeat="field in fields">  
     <td>{{ field.fieldlabel }}</td>  
  </tr>
```

My JS File:

```
var app = angular.module("myapp",[]);  
app.controller("fieldcontroller", function($scope, $http){  


    //Display Function
    $scope.displayData = function(){
        $http.get("model/select.php?type=getForm")
        .then(function(response) {                  
            $scope.fields = response.data;
            console.log($scope.fields);
        }); 
    }

 });
```

PHP File:

```
?php            

//include('Database.php');
//select.php  
//$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "kcmsuser", "KC+wSH&X#z9P", "kcms");  

        $server = 'localhost';
        $user = 'kcmsuser';
        $pass = 'KC+wSH&X#z9P';
        $dbname = 'kcms';

        $conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $dbname);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } else {        
            echo " Connected successfully ";
        }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM form";  
    $result = $conn->query($sql);


    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

         $output = array();  

         while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {

            $output[] = $row;
        }

    } else {
        echo "0 Results ";
    }   

              echo json_encode($output);
```

Console.log shows:

```
 [{"0":"110","id":"110","1":"First Name","fieldlabel":"First Name","2":"firstname","fieldname":"firstname","3":"text","fieldtype":"text","4":"","isprimary":"","5":"yes","required":"yes","6":"1","position":"1"},{"0":"23","id":"23","1":"Carrier","fieldlabel":"Carrier","2":"carrier","fieldname":"carrier","3":"text","fieldtype":"text","4":"no","isprimary":"no","5":"yes","required":"yes","6":"5","position":"5"},{"0":"26","id":"26","1":"Email","fieldlabel":"Email","2":"email","fieldname":"email","3":"email","fieldtype":"email","4":"","isprimary":"","5":"yes","required":"yes","6":"9","position":"9"},{"0":"27","id":"27","1":"Password","fieldlabel":"Password","2":"password","fieldname":"password","3":"password","fieldtype":"password","4":"","isprimary":"","5":"no","required":"no","6":"4","position":"4"},{"0":"102","id":"102","1":"Date of Birth","fieldlabel":"Date of Birth","2":"dob","fieldname":"dob","3":"date","fieldtype":"date","4":"","isprimary":"","5":"no","required":"no","6":"6","position":"6"},{"0":"101","id":"101","1":"Last Name","fieldlabel":"Last Name","2":"lastname","fieldname":"lastname","3":"text","fieldtype":"text","4":"","isprimary":"","5":"yes","required":"yes","6":"2","position":"2"}]
```

And [ngRepeat:dupes] warning.

I tried track by $index with ng-repeat but nothing happens.

I am new to Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pdo code for get data from mysql

```
<?php
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="";
    $password="";
    $dbname="";
    $dsn="mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname";
try{
    $connect=new PDO ($dsn,$username,$password);
    $connect->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
    }catch(PDOException $error){
          echo "Error in connect".$error->getMessage();
          exit();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * from `table`";  
    $result = $connect->query($sql);
$num_row=$connect->query("SELECT count(id) from `table`")->fetchColumn();

    if ($num_row > 0) {

         $output = array();  

         while($row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

            $output[] = $row;
        }

    } else {
        echo "0 Results ";
    }   
  ?>
```

Comment: thank you Mehrdad. I fixed the issue. Do you know how can I use one PHP file for all CRUD methods instead of creating separate PHP file?

Comment: can you share some examples.. i have created 3 php files (one for select, one for insert, one for delete)...Please let me have some examples of codes so I can merge CRUD in one php file....thanks

Comment: i send example for you on this post

Answer (score 0):

After spending few hours and hit and try message, I was able to sole the problem.

Problem was in the below PHP code:

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } else {        
            echo " Connected successfully ";
        }
```

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

sorry i was busy, i write code for you very fast if you have any proplem you can say me

```
   <?PHP 
    if(@$_REQUEST['delete']){
    /**************delete**************/
    $delete=$_REQUEST['delete'];
    if($connect->query("delete from table where id='$delete'")){
    echo 'delete successful';
    }}else if(@$_REQUEST['insert']=='record'){
    /**************insert**************/
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    if($connect->query("INSERT INTO `table`(`title`) VALUES ('$title')")){
    echo 'success'; }else{ echo 'error'; }
    }}else if(@$_REQUEST['edit']=='record'){
    /**************insert**************/
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $mid=$_POST['mid'];
    if($connect->query("UPDATE `table` SET `title`='$title'")){
    echo 'success'; }else{ echo 'error'; }
    }} ?>
    <h1><?PHP if(@$_REQUEST['edit']=='new'){?>insert<?PHP }else if(@$_REQUEST['edit']=='new'){?>edit<?PHP }else{?>manage<?PHP }?><h1>
    <br><a href="?insert=new">insert</a>
    <?PHP
    if(@$_REQUEST['edit']=='new'){
    $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
    $checks=$connect->query("select * from table where id='$id' order by id desc");
    $check=$checks->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    ?>
    <form>
    <input type="text" name="title" value="<?=$check['title']?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="edit" value="record">
    <input type="hidden" name="mid" value="<?=$check['id']?>">
    <input type="submit" value="edit" name="submit"/>
    </form>
    <?PHP }else if(@$_REQUEST['insert']=='new'){?>
    <form>
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <input type="hidden" name="insert" value="record">
    <input type="submit" value="create" name="submit"/>
    </form>
    <?PHP
    }else{
    $radif=0;
    $qacs=$connect->query("select * from table order by id desc");
    while ($qc=$qacs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){$radif++;
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td scope="row"><?=$radif?></td>
    <td><?=$qc['title']?></td>
    <td><a href="?delete=<?=$qc['id']?>">delete</a></td>
    <td><a href="?id=<?=$qc['id']?>&edit=new">edit</a></td>
    <?PHP }}?>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is really useful and explanatory hint. I will do some modification and use it in my code.